# Evaluate $\iint_{\Sigma} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{\sigma}$:

Tags: calculus, integration

> $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(x+1,y-2,z)$ and $\Sigma$ the part of the curved surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x\,(y\ge 0)$ bounded by the plane $z=0$ and the conical surface $x^2+y^2=z^2\,(z\ge 0)$. The normal vector is oriented away from the $z$-axis.

I don't know how to approach this problem. $\Sigma$ is, from my understanding, a vertical surface, so I don't know how to find a good under-'lying' region to evaluate the integral.

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The good under-lying region is obviously the circle $C: x^2+y^2 = 2x$ in the $xy$ plane. Since it asked for the part of the cylinder surface, you need to parametrize the cylinder and then use the formula:
$$\int_{\sum}F\cdot n dS = \iint_C F\cdot (r_{\theta}\times r_{z})dA.$$
You need an upper bound for $z$, but this is trivial since the cylinder is bounded above by the conic $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$